# Convert English into predicate first order logic.

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers, logic-translation

S(x), which stands for “x is a surgeon”
 P(x, y), which stands for “x is a patient of y”
 R(x), which stands for “x recovers”
 H(x), which stands for “x is happy”

1Express, as a formula in first-order predicate logic (not clausal form), this statement S1: “A surgeon with no patients is happy.”

2. Express, as a formula in first-order predicate logic (not clausal form), this statement S2: “A surgeon is happy if all her patients recover.”

For the first one, I have my answer as:
1. ∀(x) ∃x. (S(x)∧ ¬P(y,x) → H(x))

For the second question, I have my answer as:
2. ∀(x) (H(x) → R(x))

Are these correct? If not, what are the answers?

Answer (score 2):

No, these are not correct. Rather than give the answers directly, I will try to write out the meaning of the two statements in a way that can facilitate your re-attempting them.

$1)$ "A surgeon with no patients is happy" means: for any person $x$, if $x$ is a surgeon **and** there is no person $y$ for which $y$ is a patient of $x$, **then** $x$ is happy.

$2)$ "A surgeon is happy if all her patients recover" means: for any person $x$, if $x$ is a surgeon **and** - if for every person $y$ for which $y$ is a patient of $x$, we have that $y$ recovers - then $x$ is happy.

As an example of why your answers are incorrect, you have the following for $2)$:

> ∀(x) (H(x) → R(x))

This says,

> For any person $x$, if $x$ is happy, then $x$ recovers.

There is no mention here of surgeons, there is no mention here of patients, and you want the implication to be that patient recovery (for all relevant patients) implies happiness for the surgeon. None of this is accomplished in your proposed formulation, so take a look at the rewording at the top of this post, and give it another shot!

Comment: I modified my first answer to be: 1. ∀(x)  ( S(x)∧ ¬∃xP(y,x) → H(x))  and for the 2nd one, I have, ∀(x) (( (S(x)∧ ∀P(y,x))→ R(x) )→ H(x)). Are these correct now?

Comment: The first one is close, but be careful with parentheses and with reusing a free variable. That is, you want to assert nonexistence of y such that P(y,x); combined with S(x), this serves as the antecedent (i.e., both conditions should be in parentheses) for the conclusion of H(x). As to the second one, it is not clear what your second $\forall$ is ranging over; you must also be sure that the recovering one is the patient! Speaking of which: Give this some careful thought (i.e., be patient!) and keep trying.

Comment: okay, for the first one, I have this now: ∀(x) ( S(x)∧ ¬∃yP(y,x) → H(x) ). I changed ∃x and replaced it with ∃y.                                                                       For the second one, I have,  ∀(x) [ { S(x)∧   (∃(y)P(y,x) ∧ R(x)) } → H(x)].  I have used curly brackets for better understanding. Would you please tell me if it's alright now? Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Going by your latest attempts as stated in the comment to Benjamin's answer:

For 1), you say:

$\forall x (S(x) \land \neg \exists y P(y,x) \rightarrow H(x))$

Basically ok, but I would really recommend adding some parentheses:

$\forall x (\color{red}(S(x) \land \neg \exists y P(y,x)\color{red}) \rightarrow H(x))$

For 2), your latest attempt is:

$\forall x ((S(x) \land \exists y (P(y,x) \land R(y))) \rightarrow H(x))$

This is very close, but the surgeon wants *all* of her patients to recover in order to be happy. So:

2. $\forall x ((S(x) \land \color{red}\forall y (P(y,x) \color{red}\rightarrow R(y))) \rightarrow H(x))$